# hibernate db operation from AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler(spring)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, asynchronous, exception

I am facing the below issue when I am trying to perform a db operation from AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler(will be triggered if there is any exception in @Async method) using Hibernate.

Code Snippet:

**CustomAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler :**

```
public class CustomAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler implements AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler {

private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(CustomAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler.class);

@Autowired
private AuditService auditService;

@Override
public void handleUncaughtException(final Throwable ex, final Method method, final Object... params) {

    if (params[0] instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
        final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) params[0];
        this.auditService.auditAsyncException(ex.getMessage(), ex instanceof Exception
                ? (Exception) ex
                : null, request.getRemoteUser(), request.getRequestURI(), this.getMapOfParameters(request));
    }
    else {
        this.logger.error(String.format("Unexpected error occurred invoking async " + "method '%s'.", method), ex);
    }

}
}
```

**auditAsyncException:**

```
@Service
public class AuditServiceImpl implements AuditService {
private static final Logger LOG = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuditServiceImpl.class);
@Autowired
private AuditDao auditDao;

@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public ExceptionAudit auditAsyncException(final String message, final Exception ex, final String userid,
        final String requestUri, final Map<String, String> parameters) {

    LOG.debug("auditException");

    ExceptionSeverity severtiy = ExceptionSeverity.HIGH;

    final ExceptionAudit exceptionAudit =
            new ExceptionAudit(message, ex, userid, requestUri, severtiy, parameters, null);

    this.auditDao.saveAuditException(exceptionAudit);

    LOG.error(message, ex);
    return exceptionAudit;
}
}
```

**Error Message:**

```
ERROR [executor-1] o.s.s.a.AnnotationAsyncExecutionInterceptor.handleError(AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.java:300)| Exception handler for 
async method 'public sendSMSOrScheduleDelivery(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.Long,java.lang.String,java.lang.Long,java.util.List<java.lang.String>,java.lang.String)' threw unexpected exception itself
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:133) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:688) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.2.Final.jar:5.1.2.Final]
at .GeneralDaoImpl.getSession(GeneralDaoImpl.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
at .AuditDaoImpl.saveAuditException(AuditDaoImpl.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
at AuditServiceImpl.auditAsyncException(AuditServiceImpl.java:187) ~[classes/:na]
at CustomAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler.handleUncaughtException(CustomAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.handleError(AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.java:297) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:124) [spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at controller.MappedDiagnosticContextThreadPoolTaskExecutor$1.call(MappedDiagnosticContextThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:111) [classes/:na]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_80]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_80]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_80]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_80]
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Caused by is not in the logs you posted.  It will be helpful to add  it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following my implementation.

https://github.com/IronJhon/system_bibliotec/blob/master/src/main/java/com/system/bibliotec/config/CustomAsyncExceptionHandler.java

and

https://github.com/IronJhon/system_bibliotec/blob/master/src/main/java/com/system/bibliotec/config/async/ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.java

and

https://github.com/IronJhon/system_bibliotec/blob/master/src/main/java/com/system/bibliotec/config/AsyncConfigurationBibliotecSystem.java

In the context of AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler it is not possible to connect to beans / services managed by spring. Not that I know...

Fonte: [Custom AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48006956/custom-asyncuncaughtexceptionhandler)